# Saving console application output in an array directly

Tags: php, matlab, console-application

How can we do further comparision or computation on the output of a console application. As I believe it is in ASCII form. I have called the console application in php which gives a huge amount of numeric datas. I want that data to be saved on an array and not in a txt file as the process of reading and writing a file takes time I want it to directly save it in an array. I used exec($command,$result) but I cannot get the result to be saved in proper form. My output is as shown below:

```
    Columns 1 through 7

0.1373    0.0414    0.0541    0.1342    0.5606    0.5293    0.1652

 Columns 8 through 14

0.0341    0.0396    0.0633    0.0778    0.0289    0.0654    0.0752

Columns 15 through 21

0.3055    0.4602    0.0631    0.0360    0.0188    0.0497    0.0228...........
```

I dont want the columns line to be saved in the array and I want each element in column to be saved in different index of array. Eg array[1]=0.1373 and array [2]=0.414.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be a simple regular expression that you run on each line of the output:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\d+\.\d+/', $line, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

If the expression matches, you will have an array of results that you can use for further processing. The output for the first line that matches from your post:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.1373
    [1] => 0.0414
    [2] => 0.0541
    [3] => 0.1342
    [4] => 0.5606
    [5] => 0.5293
    [6] => 0.1652
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the output of an external command using [s,t]=system(...).
The second output shall be the string for what you have in the file.
Then you can parse the string (with regexp for example or str split utils) to extract the data as you want.